Prolog can't perform arithmetic using "=" but using "is" throws instantiation error
`I'm trying to solve a logic puzzle in prolog, I have everything working except when I run the program it doesn't add numbers together but prints them with a + in between, I tried to change the = to is in my functions but that throws and instantiation_error on my functions named second and fourth.
Here is my current code:
simpsons([carry(homer, _, _), carry(marge, _, _), carry(bart, _, _), carry(lisa, _, _)]).

first(A) :- A = bart.
second(BT, ST) :- BT = ST + 8.
third(D, C, A) :- D = C ; D = A.
fourth(MT, HT) :- MT = HT + 8.
fifth(B) :- B = homer.

answer(X) :- simpsons(X),
    member(carry(_,_,toot), X),
    member(carry(_, 10, _), X),
    member(carry(A, _, burp), X),
    member(carry(B, _, sneeze), X),
    member(carry(bart, BT, _), X),
    member(carry(C, ST, cry), X),
    member(carry(D, 6, _), X),
    member(carry(marge, MT, _), X),
    member(carry(homer, HT, _), X),
    first(A),
    second(BT, ST),
    third(D, C, A),
    fourth(MT, HT),
    fifth(B).

I get the output: X =[carry(homer,10,sneeze),carry(marge,10+8,toot),carry(bart,6+8,burp),carry(lisa,6,cry)]
And my desired output is: X = [carry(homer,10,sneeze),carry(marge,18,toot),carry(bart,14,burp),carry(lisa,6,cry)]

=, i.e. equals - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D/2 ) is for unification. Use is for arithmetic - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2

Those first, fifth etc. predicates are incomplete. E.g. fifth should have 5 variables, and make it clear that only the 5th satisfies. Could use e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3 or https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3

You can use freeze/2 to delay the calculation until the variable has a value:
second(BT, ST) :- freeze(ST, (BT is ST + 8)).
fourth(MT, HT) :- freeze(HT, (MT is HT + 8)).

and then ground/1 to make sure it's not giving answers with frozen unfinished calculations. (I don't know why it does that, I've never tried freeze before):
second(BT, ST), ground(ST),
fourth(MT, HT), ground(HT),


Otherwise, you could use CLP(FD) in SWI Prolog which can do that kind of calculation (other Prolog systems have constraint solvers also; syntax and naming may vary):
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

second(BT, ST) :- BT #= ST + 8.
fourth(MT, HT) :- MT #= HT + 8.

but it now gives negative number solutions:
?- answer(X).
X = [carry(homer,10,sneeze), carry(marge,18,toot), carry(bart,6,burp), carry(lisa,-2,cry)] ;
X = [carry(homer,10,sneeze), carry(marge,18,toot), carry(bart,14,burp), carry(lisa,6,cry)] ;
X = [carry(homer,2,sneeze), carry(marge,10,toot), carry(bart,6,burp), carry(lisa,-2,cry)] ;
X = [carry(homer,2,sneeze), carry(marge,10,toot), carry(bart,14,burp), carry(lisa,6,cry)] ;
X = [carry(homer,-2,sneeze), carry(marge,6,cry), carry(bart,14,burp), carry(lisa,10,toot)] ;
X = [carry(homer,-10,sneeze), carry(marge,-2,cry), carry(bart,6,burp), carry(lisa,10,toot)] ;

So maybe you could constrain ST #> 0 and HT #> 0 in there, too. Then it still gives multiple solutions:
?- answer(X).
X = [carry(homer,10,sneeze), carry(marge,18,toot), carry(bart,14,burp), carry(lisa,6,cry)] ;
X = [carry(homer,2,sneeze), carry(marge,10,toot), carry(bart,14,burp), carry(lisa,6,cry)]

Could there be some more information in the puzzle which isn't in the code?
